# Kafka Broker running in Docker is repeatedly restarting?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

In my dev environment, Kafka Broker usually runs fine. However, every couple of days, it gets stuck in an endless restart cycle. It would restart every ~10min and no services can connect to it. The only way for me to fix it is `docker compose down && docker compose up`. The last few log lines before restarting are a bunch of warnings like:

```
WARN [Producer clientId=_confluent_balancer_api_state-producer-1]
  Connection to node 1 (broker/172.18.0.5:29092) could not be established.
  Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
WARN [Producer clientId=ConfluentBalancerSampleStoreProducer]
  Connection to node 1 (broker/172.18.0.5:29092) could not be established.
  Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

There's also this:

```
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1000003dd170035, likely server has closed socket        
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:77)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1290)
```

A potentially relevant error that occurs earlier in the logs is:

```
ERROR Skip updating configuration of topic _confluent_balancer_partition_samples due to exception. (com.linkedin.kafka.cruisecontrol.SbkTopicUtils)
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: 
  The topic '_confluent_balancer_partition_samples' does not exist.
```

Here's the Docker Compose service (mostly copied from Confluent):

```
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.0.1
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9092:9092
      - 127.0.0.1:9101:9101
    restart: always
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://127.0.0.1:9092
      # KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=WARN,org.apache.kafka=WARN,kafka=WARN,kafka.cluster=WARN,kafka.controller=WARN,kafka.coordinator=WARN,kafka.log=WARN,kafka.server=WARN,kafka.zookeeper=WARN,state.change.logger=WARN
      KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: WARN
      KAFKA_TOOLS_LOG4J_LOGLEVEL: WARN
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
      CONFLUENT_REPORTERS_TELEMETRY_AUTO_ENABLE: 'false'
```

I'm fairly new to Kafka/Docker, I don't know what most of these settings mean. Others have suggested changing `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` and `KAFKA_LISTENERS`, but it didn't work. What are some others things I could try?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect outside the localhost (127.0.0.1), the in the broker service set the ports to:

```
ports:
  - "9092:9092"
  - "9101:9101"
```

And assuming Kakfka is on server ip 172.18.0.5 (from the logs)

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://172.18.0.5:9092
```

Comment: I don't think I'm connecting from outside localhost, all the errors are from the Kafka broker container, seems like it's failing to connect to itself? Also I tried removing 127.0.0.1, it didn't work either

Comment: @LeoJiang did you also try setting up the ip? as per logs "Connection to node 1 (broker/172.18.0.5:29092) could not be established"... it is looking the ip

Comment: I think increasing Zookeeper's timeout fixed it, that IP's generated by Docker so I can't hardcode it